# In selenium webdriver i want to use the condition select FTP if FTP present then select the HTTP ,if both present select HTTPS

Tags: webdriver

In selenium webdriver  i want to use the condition select FTP if FTP present then select the HTTP ,if both present select HTTPS.

i have a drop down 
FTP
HTTP
HTTPS

WebElement sed=BaseTest.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='comboBoxItemPicker']"));
        sed.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

```
    BaseTest.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='ftp']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get http/ftp/https from URL of the webpage then use below code and select particular value form dropdown.

String CurrentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl().toString();
String protocol = CurrentURL.substring(0, CurrentURL.indexOf("://"));

I hope it will help you.

Comment: no i need the loop condition to select any one of them

Comment: I need your html code where you want to execute because if you have many URL then store ftp/http in **protocol** variable and set in loop.